# Calling functions before they are defined (forward reference extends over definition of variable)

Tags: function, scala, variables, compiler-construction, scope

Consider this basic Scala example code:

```
object Test {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        inner()

        var x: Int = 5

        def inner() {
            println("x: " + x)
        }
    }
}
```

Trying to compile it produces the following error message:

```
test.scala:3: error: forward reference extends over definition of variable x
        inner()
        ^
one error found
```

**Questions:**

1. What is a forward reference in this context and what does it mean for it to "extend of the definition of variable x"?
2. Why does the former code raise this compile-time error?
3. How is this error caught? Seems like the compiler has to implement some interpreter-like functionality and follow function calls!

This question is not really about the order of the definitions, but exactly when a function is called. **It is completely legal for a function to be called before it is defined - but it suddenly becomes *illegal* if a variable is placed between the call and the function definition, and the function uses this variable.**

I'd like this language feature explained! Why is it there? How does it work? Are there some other more complex examples - i.e. is it just a part of some other feature or a consequence of some rules?

What I imagine the compiler is currently doing:

1. Check if the function is a closure that can access the variables of the current scope,
2. check if it does in fact access variables in the current scope, and
3. for each variable the closure accesses, check if the variable is defined before the call

Did I basically answer my third question? Is this how this behavior works? It seems to complicate the compiler a lot (especially if we consider cases with multiple levels of functions).

If that is the case, how does this integrate into the formal definition of the language, i.e. the grammar? It seems to me that the program I wrote is grammatically correct.

Comment: I'd like to say that it's a duplicate question because it comes up so often, but apparently the other questions are about when it's not obvious what the forward reference is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf:

The scope of a name introduced by a declaration or definition is the whole statement
sequence containing the binding. However, there is a restriction on forward
references in blocks: In a statement sequence s1 ...sn making up a block, if a simple
name in si refers to an entity deﬁned by sj where j >= i, then for all sk between and
including si and sj,

• sk cannot be a variable deﬁnition.

• If sk is a value deﬁnition, it must be lazy

Answer (score 2):

This error message means that forward reference in the block is not allowed. In a block, all variables (or values) must be defined in a linear order.

Note that forward references is allowed in a Class or an Object, but not a block (method definition). For example:

This will work:

```
object Test { // forward reference is allowed in an object
  def inner() {
    println("x: " + x)
  }
  var x: Int = 5
}
```

This will also work:

```
class Test { // forward reference is allowed in an class
  def inner() {
    println("x: " + x)
  }
  var x: Int = 5
}
```

But neither of these will work:

```
def main() { // forward reference for vals or vars is not allowed in a block 
  inner()

  def inner() {
    println("x: " + x)
  }

  var x: Int = 5
}

def main() {
  inner()

  var x: Int = 5

  def inner() {
    println("x: " + x)
  }
}
```

Since the val "x" is a field initialization statement, it's illegal to reference it before it is initialized ("x" contains null before it is initialized).

In-order to make it work, you can change the var to a lazy val:

```
def main() { // forward reference for lazy vals is allowed in a block 
  def inner() {
    println("x: " + x)
  }

  lazy val x: Int = 5
}
```

A legal example where the method invoking the lazy val is called before lazy val expression:

```
def main() { 
  inner()

  def inner() {
    println("x: " + x)
  }

  lazy val x: Int = 5
}
```

Without "x" being lazy, "x" would be initialized right-away which breaks the refchecks stage performed by Scala compiler.

For a little bit of theory behind this behavior, you can take a look at "Phase refchecks" section of: https://wiki.scala-lang.org/display/SIW/Overview+of+Compiler+Phases

Comment: Not really the answer I was looking for. I understand this intuitively, but I want to know the theory behind this behavior. For example, you say that all variables must be defined in order, but that doesn't explain your fourth example, where the function is defined after the variable is defined, and the only way for the compiler to know that an error exists would be to actually look up the function definition when it's being called and then conclude that it's illegal to call that function there.

Comment: @yannbane: Take a look at the Scala compiler phases. Victor Moroz's answer has a better explanation for the theory behind it.